# Xamarin forms: Issue with messaging center value passing

Tags: xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I am passing an id value through MessagingCenter. The value is passing from **Android Mainactivity** and subscribed on the **PCL ChatPageviewModel.** Please see below code:

```
// Sending group Id through the MessagingCenter on android Mainactivity
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "webcontentId", webcontentId);

//Subscribing the group id on PCL ChatPageViewmodel
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "webcontentId", (object obj, string notifWebcontentId) => 
{
    //Checking the id values and refreshing the message feed if ids are equal
});
```

**My problem is MessagingCenter.Subscribe code executing multiple times and sometimes it returns old passed id value.** I think need to add `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe` codes for solving this issue. I added like below code on OnDisappearing method.

```
 MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object, string>(this, "webcontentId");
```

**But after adding this also getting old group id values in `MessagingCenter.Subscribe`.** Is there any mistake on my `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe` code? And on where need to add `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe` codes?

Comment: If you have get the value from the `Subscribe` method in `MessagingCenter`, after that, you could `Unsubscribe` it. just put the `Unsubscribe` after the `Subscribe` method. If you can get the correct data.

Comment: Is there any mistake you found on my Unsubscribe code.

`MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object, string>(this, "webcontentId");`

Comment: No, I test your code in my project, I can Unsubscribe it.